# Get users last accessed time

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, identityserver4

I am using IdentityServer 4 (with sql storage) for my asp.net core API.  I would like to add a "Last Accessed" field somewhere in the database that can be used to order one of my user types in a user search endpoint.  Ideally this would show the last time they performed an action in the system.

If I do this in the login method it won't be accurate as it will only update when a token is initially generated.  I could add a method to every endpoint that the user accessed but this doesn't feel like the right solution as it would be repeating myself.

What is the correct place and method for maintaining a database field that records the last time a user accessed the system?

Comment: Why not doing it on the token refresh/validation endpoint? access token should be shortlived anyways (under an hour, better like 5 to 10 minutes)

Comment: How do I add code to the IdentityServer4 refresh endpoint?  The identity server and api are in different projects, I wasn't responsible for initial IDS4 setup but I cant see any renew endpoints, I think this is what IDS4 adds automatically.

Comment: IDS4 exposes events that you can implement handlers for so it’s probably worth investigating that. Also EF supports “triggers” that allow you to respond to changes to specific entities via event callback. We implemented a complete audit logging solution off the back of those two things plus adding a lot of our own events into variuous custom bits and the sign in UI

Comment: @mackie that great, I didn't see the events in the docs before but I just found them.  I had added custom middleware that writes timestamp on all authenticated requests but using events will be more performant solution.  Thanks

Comment: To avoid having to write to the database on *every* request, you could also update a timestamp of your user in-memory, and only write it back to the database every once in a while.

Comment: @poke that is a good idea

Comment: @Guerrilla, can you please tell how you solved this? Using middleware or using the events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For recording the user active time, you could try Middleware which will be called for every request.
Here are steps.
1.Add field to ApplicationUser which is store the last accessed time

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{       
    public DateTime LastAccessed { get; set; }
}
```

2.run command **add-migration LastAccessed** and  **update-database**
3.Add middleware to update the last accessed time based on the user name

```
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.Use(async (context, next) => {
            await next.Invoke();
            //handle response
            //you may also need to check the request path to check whether it requests image
            if (context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                var userName = context.User.Identity.Name;
                //retrieve uer by userName
                using (var dbContext = context.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>())
                {
                    var user = dbContext.ApplicationUser.Where(u => u.UserName == userName).FirstOrDefault();
                    user.LastAccessed = DateTime.Now;
                    dbContext.Update(user);
                    dbContext.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: i did something similar to this but I put `await next()` at end of method.  Should I have put `await next.Invoke()` at start instead?

Comment: what result did you get by `await next()`? What is your current code? You need to call `await next()` before `if (context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)`. You could put a breakpoint on `if (context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)` and `await next.Invoke` to debug whether the code runs

Comment: It seems to work (access time appears in db).  My understanding is that code calls next method in pipeline.  What is reason to call it at start?

Comment: It is caused by using this middleware before `UseAuthentication`, I have updated the order which should work no matter the order of `await next()`

Comment: I think it needs to occur after authentication or else the claim for user wont be available in context

Comment: If you invoke `next` first, you can place this wherever you want since it will run any other middleware first before doing its own processing. *However* from a performance view, you should probably place this *after* the static files middleware to avoid it from running from static file requests. It’s really enough to run this for every MVC route as those are the ones that do actual work.

Comment: @TaoZhou, i have the same requirement here, should i implement this middleware then in each and every api? we have around 30+ apis

Comment: my complier doesn't like                                                                                                    var user = dbContext.ApplicationUser.Where(u => u.UserName == userName).FirstOrDefault();                                                                                                                                                                           
                 ApplicationDbContext does not contain a definition for ApplicationUser

Answer (score 1):

I added an answer for a similar question which I did with a centralized solution in the `identity server` project (using `IEventSink`). We have 30+ apis and I found it better to do the solution in only one place instead of doing it in each and every api. So i added this answer here just in case anybody came across and have the same requirements as mine. This is my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58498502/1719433)

Comment: exactly what I needed!